# Migrar do VS 2005 para o 2012 - Alterar versão do framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Tenho um projeto compilado no .Net Framework 2.0, utilizando o VS 2005. Agora estou migrando o mesmo para o VS 2012.

A migração ocorreu com sucesso, porém o projeto não foi recompilado para o .Net Framework 4.5. A minha necessidade é recompila-lo para .Net framework 4.5.

Como posso proceder? Já Tentei alterar o web.config na tag para `Version=4.0.0.0`, mas só isso não surtiu efeito.

Comment: Relacionada: [Migrando do Framework 2.0 pro 4.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214191/migrando-do-framework-2-0-pro-4-5)

Answer (score 2):

Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto, depois em *Properties*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois escolha a aba *Application* e você vai ver uma combobox com o label "*Target Framework*".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]